# Excel powerquery: how to create a column that contains the sum of the values of other column?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have:

```
order    amount
105      2€
105      4€
105      5.50€
108      1€
108      1€
124      25€
```

Using Excel powerquery I want to create the colum "total-order". Desired result is:

```
order    amount     total-order
105      2€         11.50€
105      4€         11.50€
105      5.50€      11.50€ 
108      1€         2.00€
108      1€         2.00€ 
124      25€        25.00€
```

"total-order" colum, is the sum of the "amount" lines of each "order".

I want to keep all lines. Therefore is not valid as result:

```
order   total-order
105     11.50€
108     2.00€
124     25.00€
```

The last I know how to do using the option "group by"

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

full code if data was in range Table1:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "total-order", (i) => List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([order] = i[order]))[amount]), type number )
in #"Added Custom"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the PowerQuery UI. Begin with your data:

[image: Original data]

Define your range as a new table.

1. **PowerQuery -> From Table/Range**
2. Select your data.
3. Give the query a name -- lets say, `SourceData`.
4. **Home -> Close & Load**

Create a new query that produces the groups and totals.

1. Select the original data, including the headers.
2. **Power Query -> From Table/Range**
3. **Group By** as follows:

[image: Grouped data + total]

Merge the source data into the grouping query.

1. **Merge Queries**
2. Select `SourceData` as the second table from the dropdown.
3. Choose **Right Outer** from the **Join Kind** dropdwn.
4. Select the `order` columns in both tables.

[image: Merge Query dialog]

Currently, you'll still have the grouped rows. But if you click on the `Table` entry in the `SourceData` column, you'll see the original records that are related to this row.

Now, expand each row in the related data to a row in the main data (the groups).

1. Click on the button on the right of the header of the `SourceData` column:

   [image: Button to expand sub-tables]
2. Hide the order column:

   [image: Table Expansion dialog]

   and press `OK`.

The final results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the below function.

```
=IF(A1=A2,SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B),SUMIF(A:A,A3,B:B))
```

Column A having order, B having amount. (with header)